# Another meaning of 回{かい}転{てん} in phrase 回{かい}転{てん}寿{ず}司{し}チェーン

Tags: meaning, usage

回転 means rotation. How to understand this phrase: 回転寿司チェーン ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「回転寿司」 are those [sushi restaurant with the conveyor belt](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8), while 「チェーン」 can mean a [store chain](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3), so it seems to mean a chain of conveyor belt sushi restaurant; does it make sense, given the context?